# Cisco 1841 router killing network

Tags: cisco, switch, router

I have been trying to learn how to use the 2950's switch and the 1841 router by Cisco.

Yesterday i finally got my router (some what) set up to where i can connect my 10.22.227.x network to 10.22.226.x network.

The problem i seam to have now is that when i connect the router to my 10.22.227.x network (our main network that we have had for about a year now) it makes the network extremely slow and or we loose internet all together.

Thanks to everyone here (http://goo.gl/mfNWau) i was able to get it all set up to get thus far.

This is how i have the router set up right now.

```
enable
  configure terminal
  interface fa0/0
  description 10.22.227.254 network
  ip address 10.22.227.254 255.255.255.0
  no shutdown

  interface fa0/1
  description 10.22.226.254 network
  ip address 10.22.226.254 255.255.255.0
  no shutdown
```

A few people were telling me and from what i have read. I am going to neet to set up a outing protocol?......how do i do this?....and would this keep it from wiping out our network?

Comment: How much traffic are you trying to push through this 1841? The raw (i.e. no services/features enabled) routing performance of the 1841 is rated at 70,000 pps (or 35.84 Mbps with 64 byte packets).  This should include all concurrent input and output of all interfaces.  See [this Cisco document](http://www.cisco.com/web/partners/downloads/765/tools/quickreference/routerperformance.pdf) for full details.

Comment: Is there any chance that the IP address you've chosen for fa0/1 (the existing network) is already in use (is your internet router's address)?

Comment: @YLearn i only had 1 computer and a printer going through it.

Comment: @Ron I dont think so.... I thought i checked it out before hooking it up but im human i will double check it.

Comment: @Ron Took a look at it and I had 10.22.227.254 in the router which is the ip address of our existing networks default gateway. I changed it just to see if it made any difference (to 10.22.227.84) it does not take down the network now but i still have no internet and now i cant see the files on the computer on the 10.22.226.x network. I have internet and local network on 10.22.227.x network (the existing one)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a routing protocol, but you do need to add some static routes to make things work.

You don't mention what kind of router is your Internet gateway, but assuming it is a Cisco router, you need to add this command on it:

```
ip route 10.22.226.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.84
```

This tells the router to forward traffic to the 1841 router to get to the 10.22.226.0 network.

Then, you need to add

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.22.227.254
```

on your 1841 router.  This forwards all (non-local) traffic to the Internet gateway.

Comment: When trying to do the first function i get this `Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#ip route 10.22.226.0 255.255.255.0 10.22.227.84
%Invalid next hop address (it's this router)
Router(config)#ip route
% Incomplete command.
`

Comment: Here is a link to the show config file http://jpst.it/yp5B

Comment: the first command goes on your Internet router.

Comment: i dont have access to that router. Its managed by a different company.

Comment: Well, that changes everything. ;0  We can make it work, but we'd have to make it more complicated -- configure network address translation, so that your new devices "appear" to be on the 227 network.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info. I just thought you could just pass it though the switch(s) that i manage didnt know it was more involved then that:( I really dont have to have internet on the 226 (new network) network i really just need local network so i can move my network printers over there and clear up some space on the 227 (old network) network.

Comment: In order to do that, you will have to modify all the devices on your 227 network to use your new router as their default gateway (.84).