# Cisco Networking Router Configuration Help

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, router

I have two networks. 10.22.227.X the 227 network has the internet connection on it, I also have 10.22.226.X Network as of right now this network has no internet.

Here is the relevant configuration:

```
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address 10.22.227.1 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
ip address 10.22.226.1 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
ip classless
```

As of right now i can not communicate between the two networks. What i mean by this is... I can not access files off my computer on the 227 net work from the 226 network and visa-versa. I am using Cisco packet tracer (that's where i got my configuration file from above.) and the network work great! But when i copy it to my router it doesn't work!!!!

Can anyone help my out! I have been trying for weeks to make this work.

Comment: can you ping the remote IP address?

Comment: @RonRoyston No Not at all its almost as though the networks are not even connected with in the router

Comment: Can you please post your IP configuration of both hosts, and show ip route on the router?

Comment: @JordanHead what do you mean? How would i do that. Im sorry im trying to learn

Comment: What is the IP address, subnet mask, and gateway of each computer?  And on the router, please post the output of the following command "show ip route"

Comment: the computers are 10.22.227.x 255.255.255.0  10.22.227.254 & 10.22.226.X 255.255.255.0 10.22.226.254

Comment: router#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

Comment: First, you need to enable "ip routing" on the switch, second your, gateways are not the correct IP's.

Comment: What do you mean? how is the ip address wrong?

Comment: @ Donavon. Following on the excellent hint Jordan Head provided here is a link http://www.freeccnastudyguide.com/study-guides/ccna/ch4/ip-routing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jordanhead points out, the default gateway on your PCs on the 226 network is incorrect.  The gateway address should be the address of the router interface - 10.22.226.1  in your case.

The gateway address is where the PC should forward packets if they are not destined for the local network.  So if a PC on the 226 network wants to send traffic to the Internet, for example, it must first forward the traffic to 10.22.226.1 so that the router can forward it to your provider (or wherever else it has to go).

But that is only half your problem.  Assuming this is a continuation of your [earlier questions](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/cisco-1841-router-killing-network), the 226 network will not be able to reach the Internet until you configure your Internet router with a static route for 10.22.226.0/24 pointing to 10.22.227.1.  This tells the Internet router and all PCs on the 227 network that to reach the 226 network, the packet has to be sent to 10.22.227.1 - i.e. the router interface.

If you can't add a route to the Internet router, then you can't do what you're trying to do.  Maybe a different approach to the problem is called for.